# Using ! in ls in a script

Tags: bash, scripting, wildcards

I'm trying to list all files that do and don't contain a particular pattern in a directory. My simplified example for the first works from the command line;

```
ls -la /tmp/*-*
```

as does my command to find the inverse

```
ls -la '/tmp/!(*-*)'
```

Both return the files that I expect

When I put it in a script and call it the first one is successful and the second fails with the error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

OK so let's single quote it in the script;

```
ls -la '/tmp/!(*-*)'
ls: cannot access '/tmp/!(*-*)': No such file or directory
```

Makes sense as I guess the asterisks aren't expanded. So let's escape the braces;

```
ls -la /tmp/!\(*-*\)
ls: cannot access '/tmp/!(*-*)': No such file or directory
```

I tried double quoting both with and without escaping the braces but get similar errors. It's unclear to me why the first attempt works from the command line but not from a script. Command line is using bash and the script has the `#!/usr/bin/bash` at the top.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Edit: From the linked issue that this is a dupe of the answer is to add this to the script

```
## Enable extended globbing features
shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: Show the script. What "shebang" does it have? Sure it is not executed by `sh`?

Comment: Command line is using bash and the script has the #!/usr/bin/bash at the top